# Partial derivatives of $f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{x^2|y|}{x^2+y^4}&(x,y)\ne(0,0)\\0&(x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}$

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

We want to know how one can find out the partial derivatives of this function:

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{x^2|y|}{x^2+y^4}&(x,y)\ne(0,0)\\0&(x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}$$

I would have said

$$f_x(x,y) = \frac{2|y|^3x}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$

$$f_y(x,y) = -\frac{x^2(y^2-x^2)}{(y^2+x^2)^2}$$

Is that correct? Or do we need a case differentiation because of $|y|$?

Comment: You know that $|y|^2=y^2$, right?!

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes. Edited the post. The only case we need is for $f_x(x,y)$ where $sgn(y)$ can be positive or negative, right?

Comment: Yes, it can. And what you wrote is correct.

Comment: Also to the partial derivatives in $(0, 0) $ you have to compute them by the definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should see that all the "problems" arise when you are near $(0,0)$ . Away from it, the function itself is smooth and all the formulas work.

$$f_{x}(0,0)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}=0$$

(as $f(h,0)=0=f(0,0)$)

And $$f_{y}(0,0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(0,k)-f(0,0)}{k}=0$$ (as $f(0,k)=0=f(0,0))$

Away from the origin in the upper half plane ($y>0$) . You have

$f(x,y)=\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^4}$

And in the lower half plane ($y<0$) you have:-

$f(x,y)=-\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^4}$.

And you can calculate the partial derivatives by usual high school calculus.